# What is the name convention for Rails Models with monosyllabic like 'of'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a Ruby on Rails model for "Unit of measurement", which would be the correct form to name it?

Comment: Please read the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions). This kind of information can be easily found if you read some basic documentation..

Comment: Not found an example like the one I asking for. Only two words examples.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-classify .. and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize

Comment: I believe `UnitOfMeasurement` as the class name and `units_of_measurement` as the table. However you may need to setup a custom inflection as rails may not be able to figure out how to pluralize / constantize the compound word.

Comment: a table named ```measurements``` or ```measurement_units``` should suffice